# Storing width height and position values in javascript Not with jquery

Tags: javascript

how can I store the height ,width and position values of a DIV box within javascript (not with JQuery!) in a variable?

more specifically:

I am designing my pages for a screen resolution of 1600 width.
So I am writing a script in which all the div tags will be re-sized proportionally to the ratio of the current screen size that the client is accessing the page by the width of the page that was originally designed.

In other words I want to get dynamically all the height width and position values of all div tags and then multiply them with this ratio so that all of them will be re-sized and re-positioned proportionally.

But so far i cannot seem to be  able to store this values correctly.

this is what i have written so far:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
availW = window.screen.availWidth;
availH = window.screen.availHeight;

perNum = availW/1600;

allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

allDivsLength = allDivs.length;

for (var i=0; i<allDivsLength; i++) {
    allDivsTop = [];
    allDivsBottom = [];
    allDivsLeft = [];
    allDivsRight = [];
    allDivsWidth = [];
    allDivsHeight = [];
    changeAllDivs(i);
}

function changeAllDivs(k) {
    var i=k;
    allDivsTop[i] = allDivs[i].currentStyle.getProperyValue("top");
    allDivsBottom[i] = allDivs[i].clientBottom;
    allDivsLeft[i] = allDivs[i].clientLeft;
    allDivsRight[i] = allDivs[i].clientRight;
    allDivsWidth[i] = allDivs[i].clientWidth;
    allDivsHeight[i] = allDivs[i].clientHeight;
    allDivs[i].style.width = perNum*allDivsWidth[i]+"px";
    allDivs[i].style.height = perNum*allDivsHeight[i]+"px";
    allDivs[i].style.top = perNum*allDivsTop[i]+"px";
    allDivs[i].style.bottom = perNum*allDivsBottom[i]+"px";
    allDivs[i].style.left = perNum*allDivsLeft[i]+"px";
    allDivs[i].style.right = perNum*allDivsRight[i]+"px"; 
}
<script/>
```

Comment: Why don't you write all CSS values in percents in the first place?

Comment: ... haven't thought about it.. thanks :)

Comment: but if I didn't want to do a linear transformation like the multiplication with a ratio is  .. but it is a good idea to do it with css in the beginning , mostly I want to practice on javascript and the dom level methods.

Comment: The reason to not use jQuery is purely academical as well? `:-)`

Comment: i am just new in javascript just one and a half month and i want to first understand how javascript core functions and then move to jQuery

Comment: jQuery simplifies a lot of things. Don't even attempt crossbrowser ajax in non-throwaway code. Most browsers support `XmlHttpRequest` but then there's IE ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use CSS percentage values? Because of aspect ratio?

You could consider having a container with a fixed aspect ratio, and just resizing the one container based on the size of the client window. Anything within the container could be placed using normal CSS percentage values... Should save you some headaches later on.

Now I've modified your code slightly, see if it works better

```
availW = window.screen.availWidth;
availH = window.screen.availHeight;

perNum = availW/1600;

allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

scaleProperties = ['clientTop', 'clientBottom'] //and so on

for (var i=0; var l = allDivs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var currDiv = allDivs[i];

    for(var p in scaleProperties)
         currDiv[p] = (currDiv[p] * perNum) + "px";
}
```

Comment: actually this is my first attempt on my first webpage and generally i can say that i haven't considered many things.. i don't know what is the most preferable and safe way of doing auto-page-resizing(I don't know if there is a term like that), i am just practicing in javascript for one-two months with some tutorials .. thanks very much for the code correction i will think for this approach :)

Comment: If you're learning JS you might as well get good practice into your system and read up on execution contexts, specifically you may want to isolate functions such as this one so as not to pollute the global scope :)

Comment: yes I know that it's not good to keep a lot of globalvariables and that it is better to keep everything inside functions .. the above code was just the only thing inside the test script .. by the way is there any good documentation about how to store css values with javascript .. cause i have problems accessing styles like border-size .. border color .. i don't know which Nodes to use ..

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way no. That's why people use cross browser libraries like jQuery - they've already done the hard work of making everything parse nicely across different browsers.

Comment: you're right .. I should start looking some tutorials towards that direction ... I just thought that it would be easy for simple values like that to be stored .. but .. i can't understand actually why they make it so difficult for such simple stuff .. anyway thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get your body `Width` and `Height` in most browsers

```
var availW ;
var availH ;
if(typeof(window.innerWidth == 'number')){
    availW = window.innerWidth;
    availH = window.innerHeight;
}
else if(document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)){
    availW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    availH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
else if(document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)){
    availW = document.body.clientWidth;
    availH = document.body.clientHeight;
}
```